# How can a group manager create new users from within an Organic Group?

Tags: users, organic-groups

Is there a way for an Organic Group manager to create new users and automatically assign them to the group? Currently, OG allows the group manager to add users that have already registered to the site, but there is no form that shows something like create user form that is usually only available to the site administrators (as opposed to group managers).

I've also seen the config where the users can subscribe to the group, but it's a different case. What I want is only allow the group manager to create new users and not allow users to subscribe to the group themselves.

I've only been searching for modules and OG configs but couldn't find any relevant search results.

Comment: The [Administer Users By Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module gets you part of the way there. Also, [check out your question on the Drupal boards](https://www.drupal.org/node/1333060#comment-7674231). No answer there, but good documentation of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I'll take a look at these and see out it goes.